# Large dog lays down when eating. Should I feed in an elevated bowl and which is riskier for bloat?

Tags: dogs, health, safety, eating, large-dogs

So I have a German Shepherd/Doberman mix. Big dog that weighs about 85 pounds (around 40 kg). Not fat but large and energetic (vets says for his size he is good).

He has been eating laying down since he reached his adult height from what I can tell. He still runs, plays, jumps, etc. normally. I gave him a slow feeder as a puppy which he still eats from.

**Should I elevate his bowl to get him to stand when he eats or leave on the ground and let him lay down to eat?**

Lost a dog as a kid because of bloat and this concerns me with him. Not sure which option has the least risk.